# When using "new FirefoxDriver()" I am always getting a "NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xpath.XPathContext"

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, nosuchmethoderror, selenium-firefoxdriver

When using `new FirefoxDriver()` I am always getting a

> NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xpath.XPathContext
>
> (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.(Z)V  at
>   org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.readIdFromInstallRdf(FileExtension.java:120)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.writeTo(FileExtension.java:60)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ClasspathExtension.writeTo(ClasspathExtension.java:63)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.installExtensions(FirefoxProfile.java:464)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:442)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:79)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:195)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:107)
>     at test.PerfTest.main(PerfTest.java:35) )

Answer (score 4):

It is probably `xalan.jar` causing this. Check if you have different versions of xalan in your classpath and try checking if webdriver is referencing the correct jar. You can try

```
System.out.println(new XPathContext().getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

to check which jar it is using.

Comment: Good pickup - saved me tearing out a bit more hair and making another Stackoverflow post!